# How to build muPDF for android (Need help)

Tags: android-ndk-r5

i've been working on this for a while now but i'm still stuck. This is what i've done...

1. Installed Eclipse
2. Installed SDK, NDK
3. Created a project from an existing source... which i browsed to muPDF/android
4. Then i installed Cygwin to build the project
5. I used ndk-build to build the project by cygwin

   Then i got an error that says ".../Downloads/mupdf-0.8.165/android/jni/mupdf.c:11:19: error: mupdf.
   h: No such file or directory" 
   I've been finding a way to fix this but it keeps on having other new problems after and after. so i would like to ask for your help... plz

   Thanks in advance... Best regards, Sirisub

Answer (score 0):

In the directory above there is a script called build.sh that runs the Android.mk and other makefiles; all the locations in those makefiles are set to be run from that location.

However, there are lots of other problems, not all of which I've resolved yet; quick hints, though, you need the third-party libs like jpeg and so on in a directory called "thirdparty" in the same source location as the rest of mupdf (so as siblings of the android subdirectory) and some of the libs need you to produce config headers to make everything work!

I'm currently trying to work out how to link it all ....